# Can I access a global variable with the same name as a local variable from inside a function?

Tags: bash

Say I have the following code:

```
# Global variable x
x="Hi"

foo()
{
    # Local variable x
    local x="Hello"
}
```

Can I access (read and set) the global variable `x` from inside the function `foo()`?

Comment: Yes; before the local declaration.

Comment: Better yet, don't use globals but pass the values as parameters.  If you don't use globals it means your function code can be used in other scripts (*encapsulated*).

Comment: The easiest thing to do, if you know you need access to a global named `x`, is to give the local variable a different name.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have shadowed the global variable with a local of the same name there is no way to access the global anymore. Search for "shadow" in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html).

As mentioned you can access the global variable before declaring the local, but if that isn't what you need (e.g. if you want to write back to the global variable after declaring the local) the only option is to use a different name. It's fairly common to use a `_` or `__` prefix to denote special or private variables that should not be set at the global scope. That way all (well-behaved) callers will not collide with your variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
  1 x="Hi"
  2
  3 foo()
  4 {
  5   echo $x
  6   x="Hello"
  7   echo $x
  8   local x="Bye"
  9   echo $x
 10 }
 11
 12 foo
 13 echo $x
```

This will print:

```
Hi
Hello
Bye
Hello
```

- First `echo $x` prints the value of the global `x`
- Next we modify it, and its value is changed as you can see in line 13
- Inside `foo`, `local x` value wasn't changed

Answer (score 0):

Actually, by using a nested function, this can be done.

```
foo()
{
    local nested_ret
    foo_nested(){
        local x
        x="Hello"
        nested_ret="$x"
    }
    foo_nested "$@"
    x="$nested_ret"
}

x="Hi"
foo
echo "x is $x"
```

Output: `x is Hello`